# Why does ArrayList<E> constructor allow a raw ArrayList parameter

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure, raw-types

Why does this code compile:

```
ArrayList strings = new ArrayList();
strings.add("s1");
strings.add("s2");

ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>(strings);
```

Given that the constructor in question expects a `Collection<? extends E>` where `E` in this case is Integer? How are objects contained in the raw type `ArrayList` a subclass of `E`? Or is there some hidden compiler magic that allows this for legacy purposes?

Comment: I think this is because of compatibility. As the compiler cannot know which objects are in "strings" it assumes there are the correct ones in it. 

If the compiler behaved differently (and would not allow this), the change from (old) non generics using code to generics would be almost impossible.

Comment: This is just one instance of the well-known raw type conversion: `List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();`.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `ArrayList` constructor:

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    if ((size = elementData.length) != 0) {
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
    } else {
        // replace with empty array.
        this.elementData = EMPTY_ELEMENTDATA;
    }
}
```

The `elementData` is array of object:

```
transient Object[] elementData;
```

So new `ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)` will accept all `Collection`, don't care `E` type

It will throw `ClassCastExceptionwhen` when we use it :

```
Integer i= numbers.get(1);
```

Comment: This does not explain how elements in the raw `ArrayList` satisfy `? extends E`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should give you this warning:

> Type safety: The expression of type ArrayList needs unchecked
>   conversion to conform to `Collection<? extends Integer>`

saying that there is something wrong with the given argument (strings).

You also should get this exception when trying to run the code:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Integer

The reason you get no compile error is that the ArrayList strings is not defined correctly, you omitted the type String. So the compile may only guess that there is something worng. Change your code to

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and you'll get the compile error

> The constructor `ArrayList<Integer>(ArrayList<String>)` is undefined